# Does Rowling have an inordinate fondness for the letter H in naming characters?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

Why are there so many characters/things named with letter "H" in Harry Potter?

We have: **Harry** himself, Hagrid, **Hogwarts** school, **Helga Hufflepuff**, **Hermione**, Harry's Owl (**Hedwig**), Horace Slughorn, Hannah Abbott, Hugo Weasley (Ron/Hermione's child) and the Half-Blood Prince nickname. We have Hereward Godelot (ex-owner of the Elder Wand) and Malfoy's son's middle name (Scorpius Hyperion Malfoy). Oh, and a whole BUNCH of other minor [characters named with "H"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Harry_Potter_characters#H).

Plus, the non-character names: Holyhead Harpies team, Hog's Head bar, Honeydukes Sweetshop (which is in **Hogsmeade**).

And, oh yeah, **Horcruxes and Hallows**!

Is the letter H somehow special to Rowling? Or was that just because there were so many names used, and it's a statistical fluke? (the list of characters linked above is pretty long!)

Comment: Good Pattern look-up, but its just an evidence. I follow all interviews of Rowling.

Comment: If you look at that site you linked to, there's more character names with B C D G L M P S T & W. I think the better question would be, do YOU have a fond-ness for the letter H?

Comment: @OghmaOsiris - hopefully, hno.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In a word (a Word of God, to boot): **NO**

> **Question:** There are an extraordinary number of names that start with "H" (Harry, Hermione, Hedwig, Hogwarts, Hagrid, Hufflepuff). Is there any reason for that?
>   **J.K. Rowling responds:** Erm...no!
>   (source: "[About the Books: transcript of J.K. Rowling's live interview on Scholastic.com](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/1000-scholastic-chat.htm)," Scholastic.com, 16 October 2000)

Comment: At least no conscious reason that JKR was aware of (or willing to state). It seems unlikely at best that there wasn't some internal predilection towards the letter H.